# Why does the implementation of set() in Python involve randomization?

Tags: list, random, set

I already known when I convert list A to set, then to list again (called B), the order will be changed. But I'm quite confused why the order of the list B also changes every time the code is run.

This is my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
    print(my_list)
    print(list(set(my_list)))
```

And this is the result:
1st run:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
['2', '3', '5', '1', '4']
```

2nd run:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
['2', '4', '3', '5', '1']
```

Comment: Sets make no guarantees about the order of elements. You may not count on them being the same, and you may not count on them being different. The implementation details probably have something to do with different runs allocating different-sized chunks of memory due to heap fragmentation or something. That will cause a change in the hash function modulo table size.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thank you @LeeDanielCrocker